# how to avoid insert duplicate record in node mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Here I insert user details username,emailid and contactno and userid is primary key of user table.

My query is when i insert duplicate username or emailid and if duplicate record is heard in the table, it does not allow the record to be inserted how it is possible ?

app.js

```
app.post('/saveNewUserDetails',function(req,res){
  var form = new multiparty.Form();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){ 
    connection.query("INSERT INTO user (username,emailid,contactno) VALUES (?,?,?)", [fields.username,fields.emailid,fields.contactno] , function (error, results, fields) {
     if (error) throw error; 
      res.send({
        'status':'1',
        'success': 'true',
        'payload': results,
        'message':'New user Is saved'
      });
    });
  });
});
```

User

```
userid(primary key)    username    emailid            contactno
  1                     user-1     user1@user1.com    1234567890 
  2                     user-2     user2@user2.com    1234444444
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for every entry, we can't check the existence of that record in the database because it takes some time.

so we will set username and emailid as UNIQUE fields in your table.
so whenever we tried to insert a duplicate element into the table we will get a Duplicate key error.

Now, we will take that error as an advantage to speed up the process by simply handling it.

```
// pseudo code
// we are simply ignoring it
if( error & error != "ER_DUP_ENTRY" ){
  // do normal error handling
}
```

this is the fastest solution for avoiding duplicate insertions

Answer (score 1):

You should set `username` and `emailid` as `UNIQUE` fields in your CREATE statement.

Comment: i make username and emailid as UNIQUE but when i insert duplicate record that time i got this kind of error(Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'user-1' for key 'username' ) how to avoid this error and got message this record is already available

Comment: That's exactly what it is saying: a duplicate entry error for a `UNIQUE` field means that the record is already present in your table.

Comment: @Cynical as I understand Amisha wants to check data existence to avoid error thrown. Since question is: **how to avoid insert duplicate record in node mysql?**

Comment: Do a select on the username and one on email to check if it exists?

Answer (score -1):

**How it is possible ?** - Check for fields that You send to API with records in `user` table. Make sure they're not exist.

For more detailed information to client-side app I recommend to check database table for record existence before doing insert.

So here is solution for Your issue:

```
app.post('/saveNewUserDetails',
  async (req,res) => {
    try {
      const {fields} = await parseRequestBody(req);
      const {username, emailid, contactno} = fields;
      console.log('/saveNewUserDetails', 'fields:', fields); // for debug purposes

      const exists = await userExists(username, emailid);
      if (exists) throw new Error('User data already exists');

      const result = await createUser(username, emailid, contactno);
      res.status(201).send({
        'status': '1',
        'success': 'true',
        'payload': result,
        'message': 'New user Is saved'
      });
    }
    catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send({
        'success': false,
        'message': error.message
      }); 
    }
  }); 

const parseRequestBody = request => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(request, (error, fields, files) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve({fields, files});
    });
  });
};

const userExists = (username, emailid) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    connection.query(
      'SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = ? OR emailid = ? LIMIT 1',
      [username, emailid],
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);

        if (result && result[0]) {
          console.log('User exists:', result); // for debug purposes
          return resolve(true);
        }

        resolve(false);
      });
  });
};

const createUser = (username, emailid, contactno) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    connection.query(
      'INSERT INTO user (username, emailid, contactno) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
      [username, emailid, contactno],
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);

        resolve(result);
      });
  });
};
```